# What is the name of this kind of cache/ data structure?

Tags: algorithm, caching, data-structures

I need a fixed-size cache of objects that keeps track how many times each object was requested. When it is full and a new object is added, the object with the lowest usage score gets removed.

So this is different from a LRU-cache of size N in that if some object is heavily requested, then even adding N new objects won't push it out of cache.

Some kind of mix of a cache and a priority queue. Is there a name for that?

Thanks!

Comment: So [least frequently used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_frequently_used)?

Comment: [Here's a list of cache policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies). Surely one of those must be what you're looking for.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this scheme doesn't sound like a good idea, so maybe it's not surprising that it doesn't have a name.  What do you think this is useful for?

Comment: I wanted to use it for the task of memoization of intermediate results of complex calculations where same results are needed repeatedly, but all of them won't fit into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a time element, this kind of cache clogs up with things that were used a lot in the past, but aren't used currently. Replacement becomes impossible, because everything in the cache has been used more than once, so you won't evict anything in favor of a new item.

You could write some code that degrades the value of the count over time (i.e. take into account the time since last used), but doing so is just a really complicated way of simulating an LRU cache. I experimented with it at one point, but found that it didn't perform any better than the simple LRU cache. At least not in my application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess I'll need to do some experiments of my own to see if it will perform better than LRU.

Comment: See these [benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency) for W-TinyLFU. It ages by halving the counters periodically, storing them in a sketch rather than on the element.